# EmrResponseError: 505 HTTP Version Not Supported

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-emr

I got the following error when I ran the python file from ec2 machine.

Hadoop version: 2.4.0
ami version : 3.5.0
Boto Version : 2.32.0

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/logprocess/test_logs.py", line 182, in <module>
    job_id = emr_conn.run_jobflow(name=job_name,log_uri="s3://test.media.com/logs",hadoop_version='2.4.0',master_instance_type=test_logs_type, slave_instance_type=test_logs_type, num_instances=test_logs_size,bootstrap_actions=[bootstrap_step, heapsize_step],steps=jobsteps)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/emr/connection.py", line 581, in run_jobflow
    'RunJobFlow', params, RunJobFlowResponse, verb='POST')
  File "/home/ec2-user/.etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1196, in get_object
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EmrResponseError: EmrResponseError: 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
```